# Do you need to be running under IIS to query Active Directory with PHP LDAP

Tags: php, apache, iis, active-directory, ldap

Using PHP's LDAP support, I was curious if you need to be running under IIS in order to query the local Active Directory. Would you be able to query it if the server is running Apache instead?

Also, could I query an Active Directory setup on another machine than the code is running on, or does it need to be done on that machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as mentioned in the [documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.ldap.php), they use openLDAP, which makes no use of windows libraries/need IIS in any way. Also in the [requirements page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.requirements.php), they only say you need the libraries, with no specification of a certain server/os.

Besides, you can query other machines, that's the concept behind active directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could query also a remove active directory server. I use standard LAMPP Server to query a remote ADS.